# Apply and Cancel snapping buttons missing in QGIS?

Tags: snapping

[image: missing buttons from snapping]

In QGIS 2.14 I can't apply or cancel snapping options, these buttons are missing. I haven't got any idea, what's the problem. The system is Win 7.

Comment: Did you close the dialog with the OK or Apply buttons or with the X? Simply closing the dialog is the same as clicking on Cancel. Your parameters seem to be valid, I can snap to anything with these options. BTW, we really need to stop using jargon words unnecessarily and come up with more intuitive translations (e.g. for snapping).

Comment: Moreover, if you happen to have an UHD monitor, you can try to use map units instead of pixels. QGIS 2 is quite sloppy with calculating pixels on UHD peripherals AFAIK.

Comment: From the menubar, did you check: `Settings > Options > Digitizing > Snapping`?

Answer (score 2):

you need to enable/disable it by checking the according box (your "metszes tárgyraszter" box)

[image]

Comment: Strangely, snapping works for me without enabling snapping on intersections.

Comment: maybe you enabled snapping under settings > options > digitizing > snapping by default ?